# Incorrect rendering for inline-blocks in Chrome on Mobile

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, less

In Chrome on Android, inline-blocks have extra large spaces. On Desktop, everything is okay. Maybe it is this font boosting, but I have written the following CSS instruction: `html * {max-height:1000000px;}` and nothing has changed.

```
<div class="header__top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header__logo logo">
            <a href="" class="a logo__text" style="background: red">Logo</a>
            <div class="logo__line"></div>
            <div class="logo__description" style="background: red">Description</div>
        </div>
        <div class='header__phone' style="background: red">Telephone</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>      
</div>

.header
{
    &__top
    {
        background: #3a404c;
        height: 75px;
        min-width: 1220px;
    }
}

.header__logo
{
    float: left;

    &:before {
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        content: '';
    }
}

.logo
{
    &__text
    {
        font-size:30px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color:#fff;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    &__line
    {
        height: 50px;
        width: 1px;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        margin-right: 1rem;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    &__description
    {
        display: inline-block;
        color: #fff;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}

.header__phone
{
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;

    &:before {
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        content: '';
    }
}
```

[Inline-block extra spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC6sV.png)

Comment: Your code, [dropped into Codepen](http://codepen.io/jacefarm/pen/pNvWrj), works with Chrome 54 / Android 6.0.1.

Comment: Yes, this works in Codepen on Desktop, but in Chrome Mobile on different devices, inline-blocks have spaces as on screenshot.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the Chrome and Android versions where you are seeing the issue, to aid other users in helping you. Your code worked fine on mobile, with the versions I mentioned.  Perhaps you have other CSS that is conflicting...?

Comment: I make a small example: http://electricland.ru/primer.php
U can see this in Chrome emulator, choose  for example Galaxy S5.